# ROT47 of the current selection in SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

When doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, there is command named `Rot13 selection` which allows to [encrpyt the selected text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13).

I'd like to add a command named `Rot47 selection` that does:

```
selection = 'Test'
print ''.join(chr(33 + ((ord(ch) + 14) % 94)) for ch in selection)
#Output: %6DE
```

**Where to write this Python code in SublimeText to have this new command present in <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can write a plugin.**

Some beginner (and not 100% correct) code is available [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-examples).

A complete plugin for Rot47 would have the following code:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class Rot47Command(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for region in self.view.sel():
            if not region.empty():
                s = self.view.substr(region)
                s = ''.join(chr(33 + ((ord(ch) + 14) % 94)) for ch in s)
                self.view.replace(edit, region, s)
```

**Where to write this code?**

Tools > New Plugin... will open a new buffer with some boilerplate code. Replace the boilerplate with the above code and save the file as `rot47.py` in `/<sublime-text-dir>/Packages/User/`.

You can test the above plugin by opening the console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, and typing `view.run_command('rot47')` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Make sure that you've selected some text before running your new Rot47 command.

Furthermore, if you want to create a keyboard shortcut for your new rot47 command: go to Preferences > Key Bindings -- User and add the following entry:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+4"], "command": "rot47" }
```

(you can of course choose a more meaningful key combination.)

**What did the above plugin code do?**

`self.view.sel()` gives an iterable on the selected text regions (there can be multiple selections in the same buffer, go Sublime!). A region is basically a `(start_index, end_index)` pair that denotes a selected substring. `self.view.substr(region)` gives you the required substring.

We then modify the selection text (variable `s`) as desired and replace the selection with the new text (the call to `self.view.replace()`).

For a more extensive API reference, see [this](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.View).

Comment: @Basj I changed the `replace` call a bit, please try and let me know if it works. It works for me in sublime 3.

Comment: @Basj you can add new commands to command palette. See [this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html) for reference.

Comment: Creating a `Default.sublime-commands` file in `C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User` containing `[{ "caption": "ROT47", "command": "rot47" }]` will add it to CTRL+SHIFT+P

Comment: As a hint, the default "rot13" command is also implemented as a plugin and you can check its source code using [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) and browsing `Default → transform.py` with it. The code structure is kind of weird however.